# I want to assign a variable to the column of a gridview of ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, variable-assignment

I don't know how to assign a variable (newvalue) to the column of GridView table which is:  `<asp:BoundField DataField="convertedValue" DataFormatString="{0:n2}" HeaderText="Value in" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="convertedValue" />`

and the code provided is :

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtSecurityHolding.Rows){
                int shares = myHKeInvestCode.getColumnIndexByName(gvSecurityHolding, "shares");
                int price = myHKeInvestCode.getColumnIndexByName(gvSecurityHolding, "price");

                int newvalue = myHKeInvestCode.getColumnIndexByName(gvSecurityHolding, "value");
                newvalue = shares * price;

                // Add your code here!
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If your grid binds to dtSecurityHolding then you should put the value like that:

```
 row["convertedValue"] = newvalue;
```